# Printing HTML styled lists from vectors in R

Tags: html, r

I have a vector in .Rmd file let's say

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

I want to print and export this file to html or doc file to look like

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use HTML tags in rmarkdown files as long as you don't indent them at all. So add something like ``<ul>`r paste0('<li>', x, '</li>', collapse='')`</ul>`` in your file.

Answer (score 1):

We can do

````
```{r, code2, results = "asis", echo = FALSE}
cat(paste("*", x), sep="\n")

```
````

-output

[image]